# Prevent form submission by checking every dynamically created text boxes are empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here I am trying to check each and every `dynamically` created `textboxes` whether it is `empty` or not before the `form` submission.

Here is the `HTML` code,

```
<form>
<table class="table table-hover table-white">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-sm-1">Test ID</th>
        <th class="col-md-6">Test Name</th>
        <th style="width:100px;">Amount</th>
        <th> Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="rows">
    <tr>
        <td> <input class="form-control test_id" type="text" style="width:200px" id="test_id" onblur="checkname(this);" onkeyup="checkname(this);" onchange="checkname(this);"> </td>
        <td> <input  type="text" style="width:300px" class="form-control test_name"  readonly="" id="test_name"  onblur="checkname();" onkeyup="checkname();" onchange="checkname();"></td>
        <td> <input  type="text" style="min-width:100px" class="form-control amount" name="amount" readonly=""> </td>
        <td><center> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-success font-18" title="Add" id="add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a> </center> </td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
                                                                 
                                                          
<span id="test_id_info" class="info text-danger"></span>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label>Other Information</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="description"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
                                                     
<div class="text-center m-t-20">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn" name="pay"value="Generate Invoice" id="pay">
</div>

</form>
```

Here is the `Ajax` code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var count=0;
$(document).on('click','#add',function() {
count++; 

var html= '';
html += '<tr id="trrows">';

html += '<td id="testid"> <input id="test_id" class="form-control test_id" type="text" style="width:200px" onblur="checkname(this);" onkeyup="checkname(this);" onchange="checkname(this);" onblur="sum(this);" onkeyup="sum(this);" onchange="sum(this);"> </td>';

html += '<td id="testname"> <input id="test_name"  type="text" style="width:300px" class="form-control test_name"  readonly="" onblur="checkname();" onkeyup="checkname();" onchange="checkname();"> </td>';

html += '<td id="amounts">  <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" style="min-width:150px" class="form-control amount"  readonly="" > </td>';

html += '<td><center> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-danger font-18 remove" title="Remove" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></center> </td>';

html +=  '</tr>';
$('#rows').append(html);
  
});

$(document).on('click','.remove',function() {
$(this).closest("#trrows").remove();

});

});

//  generate bill 

$(document).on('click', '#pay', function () {

var test_id = new Array();
$('input[id="test_id"]').each(function() {
test_id.push(this.value);
});

var amount = new Array();
$('input[name="amount"]').each(function() {
    amount.push(this.value);
});

var p_id = $('#p_id').val();
var pres_id = $('#pres_id').val();
var description=$('#description').val();

var valid;
valid = validateContact();

if (valid) {

    swal({
title: "Are you sure?",
text: "You wanna proceed this Payment!",
type: "warning",
showCancelButton: true,
confirmButtonClass: "btn-success",
confirmButtonText: "Yes, Proceed It!",
closeOnConfirm: false
},
function(isConfirm){
if (!isConfirm) return;
$.ajax({
        url: "testquery/test_payments.php", // Url to which the request is send
        method: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: {   
         'test_id': test_id,
         'amount': amount,
         'p_id': p_id,  
         'pres_id': pres_id, 
         'description':description
           },     

        success: function (data) {
        if (data == 'Password Changed') {
            swal("Success", "Invoice has been Generated :)", "success");

        } else {
            swal("Sorry", "Something Went Wrong. Please try again later:(", "error");
        }
    },

    error: function (data) {
           //other errors that we didn't handle
        swal("Sorry", "Failed to Proceed. Please try later :(", "error");
    }
    });
});  
};

// check validations
function validateContact() {
    var valid = true;
    $(".demoInputBox").css('background-color', '');
    $(".info").html('');

    if (!$("#test_id").val()) {
    $("#test_id_info").html("(Required)");
    $("#test_id").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
        }
  
    return valid;
}

});
```

I want to check the `test_id` `textbox` is `empty`. Before dynamically generating the `textboxes` there, already there is a row of `textboxes` including `test_id` `textbox`. My problem is, before generated, it check the `textbox` as `empty` or not by using `function`, but after generated it does not check. I don't know where I went wrong.

Please help me may highly appreciated.

Comment: You should create all your textboxes (both static and dynamic) to have an HTML attribute named `required` - then the browser will automatically check them for being empty.

Comment: both static and dynamic `textboxes` is the same `name`.

Comment: They should always have the attribute `required` - then the browser will prevent form submission if any of the textboxes is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the elementID use class name to get the collection of elements and iterate through them. the problem we have here is all input have the same id so jquery will return the first element it finds and ignore the rest since with ID we assume that it is unique throughout the DOM

```js
function checkname(el){

}
$(document).ready(function(){

var count=0;
$(document).on('click','#add',function() {
debugger;
count++; 

var html= '';
html += '<tr id="trrows">';

html += '<td id="testid"> <input id="test_id" class="form-control test_id" type="text" style="width:200px" onblur="checkname(this);" onkeyup="checkname(this);" onchange="checkname(this);" onblur="sum(this);" onkeyup="sum(this);" onchange="sum(this);"> </td>';

html += '<td id="testname"> <input id="test_name"  type="text" style="width:300px" class="form-control test_name"  readonly="" onblur="checkname();" onkeyup="checkname();" onchange="checkname();"> </td>';

html += '<td id="amounts">  <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" style="min-width:150px" class="form-control amount"  readonly="" > </td>';

html += '<td><center> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-danger font-18 remove" title="Remove" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></center> </td>';

html +=  '</tr>';
$('#rows').append(html);
  
});

$(document).on('click','.remove',function() {
$(this).closest("#trrows").remove();

});

});

//  generate bill 

$(document).on('click', '#pay', function () {

var test_id = new Array();
$('input[id="test_id"]').each(function() {
test_id.push(this.value);
});

var amount = new Array();
$('input[name="amount"]').each(function() {
    amount.push(this.value);
});

var p_id = $('#p_id').val();
var pres_id = $('#pres_id').val();
var description=$('#description').val();

var valid;
valid = validateContact();

if (valid) {
alert('invoice generated')
   
};

// check validations
function validateContact() {
debugger;
    var valid = true;
    $(".demoInputBox").css('background-color', '');
    $(".info").html('');

//list of test_id inputs
var testIdList = 
document.getElementsByClassName('test_id')
for(let i= 0 ; i<testIdList.length; i++){
    if (!testIdList.item(i).value) {
    $("#test_id_info").html("(Required)");
    $("#test_id").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
        }
        }
  
    return valid;
}

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<table class="table table-hover table-white">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-sm-1">Test ID</th>
        <th class="col-md-6">Test Name</th>
        <th style="width:100px;">Amount</th>
        <th> Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="rows">
    <tr>
        <td> <input class="form-control test_id" type="text" style="width:200px" id="test_id" onblur="checkname(this);" onkeyup="checkname(this);" onchange="checkname(this);"> </td>
        <td> <input  type="text" style="width:300px" class="form-control test_name"  readonly="" id="test_name"  onblur="checkname();" onkeyup="checkname();" onchange="checkname();"></td>
        <td> <input  type="text" style="min-width:100px" class="form-control amount" name="amount" readonly=""> </td>
        <td><center> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-success font-18" title="Add" id="add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a> </center> </td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
                                                                 
                                                          
<span id="test_id_info" class="info text-danger"></span>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label>Other Information</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="description"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
                                                     
<div class="text-center m-t-20">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn" name="pay"value="Generate Invoice" id="pay">
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class, name or other attributes instead id, because you have a several elements with the same ids - it's always create problems. If you need check inputs with class "text_id" before submit try to change validation function

```
function validateContact() {
    var valid = true;
    $(".demoInputBox").css('background-color', '');
    $(".info").html('');

    $('.text_id').map(function(i, el){        
        if(!$(el).val() || $(el).val().trim() == '') {
            valid = false;
            $("#test_id_info").html("(Required)");
            $(el).css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
        }
    });
  
    return valid;
}
```